# PowerShell regular expression on logfile is capturing too much

Tags: regex, powershell

I am trying to extract some text from a logfile, and I'm having problems.
Example text I am working on is:

```
ahksjhadjsadhsah
sakdsjakdjks
ksajdksaj
REF=35464
sadsad
213213
213
2
13
```

I need to extract the value "35464" (the REF number). I have limited knowledge of regular expressions, but thought 'REF=([0-9]+)' would do this.

Now I'm not sure how best I should be doing reading this file, so I've tried a couple of ways:

```
select-string -path e:\powershell\log.txt -pattern 'REF=([0-9]+)' | % { $_.Matches } | % { $_.Value }
```

Which gives me "REF=35464" - which I don't understand (why REF= is included), because I thought the 'capture' was only the parts in ()'s?

I also tried:

```
$data=Get-Content e:\powershell\log.txt
$data -match 'REF=([0-9]+)'
$Matches
```

But $Matches is empty.

I also tried a similar method to the above, but line by line, for example:

```
foreach ($line in $data)
{
    $line -match 'REF=([0-9]+)'
}
```

I either get no matches or the full match (including the REF= part). I've also tried groups (that is, '(REF=)([0-9]+)'), and I can't get what I need.

How should I be reading the file? What is wrong with my regular expression?

I just need this extracted value as a usable variable.

Comment: Try `'(?<=REF=)[0-9]+'` if you need just the number.

Answer (score 1):

It may be the way you are trying to access the capture group

I put this quick static class together to illustrate how to get the match you are looking for.

Note: I am using the @ symbol on the regex and your input string to make them literals.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace SkunkWorks.RegexPractice
{
    public static class RegexPractice2
    {
        public static string input = @"ahksjhadjsadhsah
        sakdsjakdjks
        ksajdksaj
        REF=35464
        sadsad
        213213
        213
        2
        13";

        static string pat = @"REF=([0-9]+)";

        public static void Do()
        {
            Regex r = new Regex(pat, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);

            Match m = r.Match(input);

            int matchCount = 0;

            while (m.Success)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Match" + (++matchCount));
                for (int i = 1; i <= 2; i++)
                {
                    Group g = m.Groups[i];
                    Console.WriteLine("Group" + i + "='" + g + "'");
                    CaptureCollection cc = g.Captures;
                    for (int j = 0; j < cc.Count; j++)
                    {
                        Capture c = cc[j];
                        System.Console.WriteLine("Capture" + j + "='" + c + "', Position=" + c.Index);
                    }
                }
                m = m.NextMatch();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What I usually do when I need to extract a substring from an array of strings is to use the automatic variable `$Matches` that is generated from using the `-match` operator in a `Where` statement. Like this:

```
$Data | Where{$_ -match "REF=([0-9]+)"} | ForEach{$Matches[1]}
```

Now, the `$Matches` variable there will be an array. The first entry will be the entire line that it matched, and the second object will be just the captured text, that is why I specify `[1]`. Now, about your RegEx that you're matching on... technically it's acceptable, but it's not very specific, so it really could return just the first number since `[0-9]+` means 1 or more character that falls within the `[0-9]` scope. If you want to be sure that you get all of the numbers you can tell it to get everything to the end of the line by using the end-of-line character `$` in your match like: `REF=([0-9]+)$`. We can't really tell if there's any whitespace after the numbers, so you might want to allow for that too using the `\s` notation that looks for any whitespace character (spaces, tabs, whatever), and using the asterisks after it which means zero or more. Then it becomes `REF=([0-9]+)\s*$`, which gets you exactly what you were looking for. Lastly, I would use `\d` instead of `[0-9]` because it does the same thing and it's shorter and simpler, and specifically made for the job. So, we have:

```
$Data | Where{$_ -match "REF=(\d+)\s*$"} | ForEach{$Matches[1]}
```

And that is broken down step by step and explained here: https://regex101.com/r/dG7jC7/1